# Proper definition of spec file for upgrading libraries

Tags: rpm, autotools, libtool, rpm-spec

There is a library package that I'm responsible for distributing.  Some time ago, the build system was switched from our home-baked `Makefile` to using GNU Autotools.  As such, using `libtool`, we now have the ability to easily manage multiple installed versions of the library.  Having switched to RPM for distribution, I'd like to know how I can "doctor" the spec file to refrain from completely uninstalling previous versions when upgrading.

For example, after installing version 1.0.0 of a dummy library project I have

```
[afalanga@afalanga4 libtest]$ ls /usr/lib64/libaby*
/usr/lib64/libabyss.a   /usr/lib64/libabyss.so    /usr/lib64/libabyss.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libabyss.la  /usr/lib64/libabyss.so.0
```

Then, after `sudo yum localupdate ....` I have the following:

```
[afalanga@afalanga4 libtest]$ ls /usr/lib64/libaby*
/usr/lib64/libabyss.a   /usr/lib64/libabyss.so    /usr/lib64/libabyss.so.0.0.1
/usr/lib64/libabyss.la  /usr/lib64/libabyss.so.0
```

Of course, as a libtool-produced library the only "real" files are: `libabyss.a, libabyss.la and libabyss.so.0.0.1`.  What should be done in the spec file to ensure that `libabyss.so.0.0.0` stays after `libabyss.so.0.0.1` is installed?  The symbolic links will be take care of accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real way to do what you're trying to do because the symlink that is used to load the library is managed by `ldconfig` and are based on the SONAME of the library (see [my post on the topic](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/10/a-shared-library-by-any-other-name/). So even if you kept `.so.0.0.1` nothing would ever be using it.

If you want them for compatibility because they may be different ABIs, then you'll have to make sure the [versioning is done correctly](https://autotools.io/libtool/version.html) but it doesn't seem to be the case from what I can read.

Other than that, I'm not sure if RPM has any special case to keep multiple version of a given library in these cases, because there should really be no need for that to happen.

Comment: Right, I was wondering the full effect of the _current_ and _age_ parameters on the _SONAME_ in the library.  I am planning to use the *-release <version>* flag when building an actual release for the RPMs as well.  There are a total of 6 libraries installed: 2 of which I'll use the -release flag.  The others do not change often.  Yes, I know they should be separate, but presently, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that won't really work.  The usual GNU Build System assumption for library versioning is to use the scheme [described here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libtool-versioning.html) for [computing](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html#Updating-version-info) the values you set for `-version-info`.  As Diego alluded to, even if you were able to convince RPM to leave those old libs around (IIRC, I think you can when rpm is run), the old versions share the same SONAME as the old one (e.g. `libabyss.so.0`) and would essentially be orphaned when `ldconfig` is run on the library install/upgrade.

Usually when folks want to do this they'll use the libtool `-release` flag or rename the RPM package like `libabyss0`, `libabyss1`, etc. to put the SONAME version number upfront.

Comment: Right, I had found the -release flag and I do plan to use it.  The library we release is a collection of libraries actually.  For two of them, I'd planned on using the - release flag as they are the more "customer facing" libraries.